# Getting the 100 most recent DB entries from SQL DB via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm very new to php/SQL (1 day) so forgive me if I am doing this in a backwards way.

This php below is intended to return the 100 most recent entries into the DB. I attempt to do it by selecting 100 entries to be returned and sort by the date(time stamp) the entry was made. Will this return the 100 more recent entries to the DB? Or am I understanding this wrong?

```
    $type   = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : "global";
$offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : "0";
$count  = isset($_GET['count']) ? $_GET['count'] : "100";
$sort   = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : "date DESC";

// Localize the GET variables
$udid  = isset($_GET['udid']) ? $_GET['udid'] : "";
$name  = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name']  : "";

// Protect against sql injections
$type   = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
$offset = mysql_real_escape_string($offset);
$count  = mysql_real_escape_string($count);
$sort   = mysql_real_escape_string($sort);
$udid   = mysql_real_escape_string($udid);
$name   = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

// Build the sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ";

switch($type) {
    case "global":
        $sql .= "1 ";
        break;
    case "device":
        $sql .= "udid = '$udid' ";
        break;
    case "name":
        $sql .= "name = '$name' ";
        break;
}

$sql .= "ORDER BY $sort ";
$sql .= "LIMIT $offset,$count ";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

if(!$result) {
    die("Error retrieving scores " . mysql_error());
}
//echo $result;
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, although `date` is a MySQL keyword, so you would either need to enclose `date` in backquotes or rename that column.

Also, **definitely** make sure you've sanitized those inputs before building your query. Building a query off of user-editable values from `$_GET` or `$_POST` with no sanitation is *very* unsafe.

For `WHERE` parameters, you should be running `mysql_real_escape_string()` on those (which I see you are, I'm not sure if you were before or not). That's enough because you're wrapping those values in quotes in your query, and since you're escaping that string, any attempt to break out of those quotes won't work.

For the stuff like the `ORDER BY` you have, I would define a valid "list" of allowed values and check to make sure your parameter is in that list. For example:

```
$valid_orderbys = array('`date` DESC', '`date` ASC', '`name` DESC', '`name` ASC');

if (in_array($_GET['sort'], $valid_orderbys))
{
    // you're good, you can use this value
}
else
{
    // unexpected value, either alert the user or 
    // use a default value you define
}
```

Or for `LIMIT`, you could use PHP's built-in `is_numeric()` to verify that the value you're being given is a number, not a crafted string.

It's **not** enough to simply escape the `$table`, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` parameters because they're not wrapped in quotes and therefore someone can just maliciously inject a value of `; DROP TABLE whatever; --`. This ends up making your query something like:

```
SELECT * FROM ; DROP TABLE whatever; --WHERE ...
```

Queries are separated by semicolons, so there are three queries here. The first fails because it's invalid, the second succeeds in dropping the table, and the third is just a comment so nothing happens. But you can see, if you let users throw whatever they want as one of those parameters, it's a wide open security hole. (I'm not sure if enclosing the table name in backquotes helps this, someone let me know if you know. But in any case, you can do the same attack on the `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` parameters.)

Comment: This might be my greeness showing, but what do you mean by "sanitized those inputs" Can you give me and example of what "sanitizing' is?

Comment: I expanded on my answer, check it out. And let me know if you have any other questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you already got it right. You should only look into specifying the columns instead of using *.

Comment: altho to be concise, you want to LIST all the columns you need, not just be lazy and do `*`

Comment: Ugh, wrong database. My mistake. And the * was because OP did not include the columns in question. I edited the post to be more compliant.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique, auto-increment ID for each record (as you should), it would be more efficient to `ORDER BY id DESC`.

Comment: ORDER BY id DESC will give me the 100 more recent additions to the DB or the first 100?

Comment: @Code: ORDER BY id ASC will give you the first 100.